# JQuery POST не работает в IE Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

вот есть такой код

```
function Ajax_find(name) {
    if(name.length > 1){
        $.post("/search", {'имя': name}, onAjaxSuccess);
        function onAjaxSuccess(data)
        {
            document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(data);
        }
    }
}
```

В хроме всё нормально работает, Firefox не отправляет запросы на сервер, а IE8 запросы посылает но ответ не получает, просто волею судеб приходится делать фронтэнд, а в нём я совсем не силён, сервер самописный на Node

HTML часть такая

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="name" size="30" onkeyup="Ajax_find(this.value)" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
    <div id="search"></div>
    <p><b>Поиск по</b></p>
    <input type="radio" name="browser"  checked="checked"> Фамилии
    <input type="radio" name="browser" > Имени
    <input type="radio" name="browser" > Отчеству
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. не используёте русские названия параметров
2. чаще смотрите в консоль, FF четко пишет, что не может найти функцию onAjaxSuccess, и правильно делает - нечего их внутри функция таким образом объявлять. Либо определите функцию-переменную выше аякса, либо саму функцию в глобал перетащите.

либо как я сделал см. http://jsfiddle.net/SanSYS/wj5gttkL/

```js
function Ajax_find(name) {
  if (name.length > 1) {
    $.post("/search", {
      'name': name
    }, function onAjaxSuccess(data) {
      document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = decodeURIComponent(data);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" size="30" onkeyup="Ajax_find(this.value)" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
  <div id="search"></div>
  <p><b>Поиск по</b>
  </p>
  <input type="radio" name="browser" checked="checked">Фамилии
  <input type="radio" name="browser">Имени
  <input type="radio" name="browser">Отчеству
</form>
```

---

PS: см. консоль только на jsfiddle, здесь что-то не то )

Comment: Понятно, вынес ф-цию наружу и всё ок, а с IE8 то чего я и боялся, он нормально не поддерживает [innerHTML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897.aspx)

Comment: @vnn198, используйте jquery.html функцию)

Comment: да непоможет ибо "This method uses the browser's innerHTML property"  . а косяк IE в том что у него почти все innerHTML property только чтение